# Identify the programming language from the given block of code

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

I am using the SyntaxHighlighter plugin in one of my projects and What the question is I want to identify the programming language from the given block of code on document load. I have written the block of code in between the "pre" tag in a HTML page. Hope I am clear and Please help me. It's very important for me.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve the `pre` tag from the text file ?

Comment: Hello @Yves Daoust thanks for your reply, I am not writing to a text file and I am writing on an HTML page.

Comment: An HTML file is a text file. If you open it with a text editor or as a stream, you'll see the tags.

Comment: It's k. Previously I just tried the same thing with highlight.js plugin and its given the result, but it's failed while identifying all languages. So, I have configured SyntaxHighlighter.js file. Please tell me whether it is possible to know the programming language or not?